# Can't use "Onblur" in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

The JavaScript handler is not called.
In the below code is not working in Firefox (latest version). However, it works fine in google chrome

```
# 1
<input onblur="myOnBlurHandler(event)" />

# 2
<input class="my_input" />

var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("my_input");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].addEventListener("blur", myOnBlurHandler);
}

function myOnBlurHandler(evt) {
  alert("yes");
}


# 3
<input class="my_input" />

var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("my_input");
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].addEventListener("onblur", myOnBlurHandler);
}

function myOnBlurHandler(evt) {
  alert("yes");
}
```

Comment: first two of those three works in firefox 66.0.2 in windows 10 - second one ends up calling the handler twice, because that's what you coded, and the third one only once, because there's no such thing as an `onblur` event, it's a `blur` event (when using `addEventListener` - but, in essence, they all work identically in chrome and firefox - you probably did something wrong™

Comment: These work in Firefox; if you're using the code exactly as you show it above, perhaps your problem is that the script tag is missing? `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: These work in Firefox; if you're using the code exactly as you show it above, perhaps your problem is that the script tag is missing? `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: `type="text/javascript"` has not been needed > 10yrs AFAIK